# Updating array within array mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Hi I am new to mongDB and I am trying to push some new elements inside my array. I have an array `rules` which contains another array named `rule1` that stores `hash` and `date`. I want to push new data to `rule1` array.

Document in mongoDB:

```json
_id: ObjectID('643eef196a3a623bc8abc8ac'),
user_email: "mail",
user_name: "name",
rules: [
  {
     rule1:  [
              { 
               "hash":"aaa",
               "date": "1/1/1" 
              },
              { 
               "hash":"bbb",
               "date": "2/2/2" 
              },
            ],
  },
  {
     rule2: [
              { 
               "hash":"ddd",
               "date": "4/4/4" 
              },
              { 
               "hash":"eee",
               "date": "5/5/5" 
              },
            ]
  },
  {
     rule3: [
              { 
               "hash":"fff",
               "date": "6/6/6" 
              },
              { 
               "hash":"ggg",
               "date": "7/7/7" 
              },
            ]
  }
]
```

So I tried this:

```
all_updates = {
        "$push":{"rules.$.rule1": {"hash": "cccc", "date": "34"}}
    }

    collection.update_one({"_id": _id}, all_updates)
```

But it throws some error like this:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query., full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 2, 'errmsg': 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.'}
```

I found some solution fir this error but i could not resolve it. Can some one tell me wha tam i doing wrong with my update and how to fix it ?

Comment: how to know whch position it needs to push. for example u can use `"rules.0.rule1"` if u know its the first

Comment: @cmgchess And if i have multiple rules ? For example like `rule2,3,4..`. And in my applications they have custome names so I can't use those numbers science i dont know what names they will have.

Comment: then you need some condition to find the needed position. can you expand your question with a larger document

Comment: @cmgchess sure, i expanded it.

Comment: by the way why not have structure like `rules: {rule1:[],rule2:[]...}` instead of an array. if this was the case it would be straightforward. otherwise u might have to do something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/sr-21FhPZLj

Comment: @cmgchess Well as I said I am new to mongo and I was trying to create some structure of my document and this was what I come up with. But I consider recreating it. Thank you.

Comment: Just another implementation similar to @cmgchess's. You can refer to the link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Obv0yab-c1

Comment: @wondergrandma Please also consider a single record of Mongo document can't exceed the size of 16 MB. You should consider the number of rules, you might need to create a new collection as rules and refer to it.